# How to set labels based on max and min value of the plot?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

im using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library to plot line graph. On the left side I want to have 3 labels. Min, max and one in the middle of the graph.

I set the granulation based on the min and max value:

```
graphView.leftAxis.granularity = (data.yMax - data.yMin)/2.0
```

So the spacing is now correct, but the problem still left with the grid offset. Because it starts drawing at 0.0 but I want it to start a the minimum value of the graph.

Is it possible? Do you know any workaround?

Some additional code for presenting graph data:

```
let data = graphPacket.getChartData()
graphView.data = data

let space = (data.xMax - data.xMin)*0.01
graphView.xAxis.axisMaximum = data.xMax + space
graphView.xAxis.axisMinimum = data.xMin - space

let hSpace = (data.yMax - data.yMin)*0.05
graphView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = data.yMax + hSpace
graphView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = data.yMin - hSpace

graphView.leftAxis.granularity = (data.yMax - data.yMin)/2.0
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your full code, please

Comment: I added the additional code. I think its enough. I only need to know if its possible to begin the grid elsewhere than from zero line.

Comment: cna you please log what you get in `data.xMin` ?

Comment: Im mostly insrested in vertical values (y axis). Max = 0.17807827369999998, min = 0.1232531151